# how do i set socket options in nodejs for zeromq

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

in other languages its socket.setsockopt but that doesn't seem to work for https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that library exposes the options as getters and setters. So to print the sendBufferSize you should be able to do the following.

Check out the code around line 80 https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/zeromq.js

```
var sys = require("sys");
var zmq = require('zeromq');

s = zmq.createSocket('req');
console.log(s.sendBufferSize);
```